# WordPress Site Displays Correctly in 'Customize' View but Not on Live Site

Tags: wordpress, header, customizer

I'm facing a issue with my WordPress site where the header displays some issues, for example: the logo is huge and the menu links are stacked, as if some css code is missing. The peculiar thing is that when I use the 'Customize' view (accessible via the WordPress admin bar), everything looks as it should... I don't know how it's possible since that I should be editing a live version of the site when changing the setting in "Customize".

I'm using the latest WordPress version. My theme is Startor and it uses Elementor/Pro.
I suspect this is a conflict with a theme plugin (startor-core) but I don't know where to look for error messages regarding what's happening.

I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

The chrome dev console shows no errors regarding that.
I've cleared all caches, including CDN.

Comment: Does this also happen with a fresh install of the theme? You should rule out whether this is a bug in the theme or whether you have changed one or more settings that cause the behaviour.

Comment: As the responses below mention, you can try debugging if any plugin or theme conflicts with WP_DEBUG enabled OR try switching to the default theme.
Also, you can try disabling CDN until development work is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please enable the WordPress DEBUG mode.

**Enable WordPress debugging:**
Enable WordPress debugging by editing your wp-config.php file. Set define('WP_DEBUG', true); and check for any error messages on the front end.

**Plugin Conflict:** Deactivate all the plugin and then activate these one by one and then see if the website is look's fine. And figure out which plugin causing the issue. Also please check the customization button is on publish mode not on save as draft,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create a new website.
Install theme is Startor and it uses Elementor/Pro.
Add your logo.
And go live with that version to see how it works.
Continue diagnose.